# Cannot access Public method in Web Control's Page_Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to call my `Public String Function(...)` method from my `.ascx`'s `Page_Load` event. The function and containing class are located in the same code behind as the web control. But I am unable to access the function. How can I resolve this problem?

Example:

```
public class Controls_WebApp : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IAttributeAccessor, IUserControlDesignerAccessor
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call Function
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Function(string path)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Explain the actual problem. From what you described, you should be able to create an instance "var myClass = new A();" and then call your method "var result = myClass.Function("some arg");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands you will need an instance of `A` to invoke the method

```
using namespaceOfA;
...
string result = new A().Function("Hello world");
```

Alternatively if the function has no reliance on the state of A, you can make the function static (`public static string Function`)

```
string result = A.Function("Hello world");
```