# How do you access a function in Page_Load

Tags: c#, function, class, controls, pageload

This question is like [Cannot access Public method in Web Control's Page_Load event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470394/cannot-access-public-method-in-web-controls-page-load-event/44703352?noredirect=1#comment76389643_44703352)

However since you are not allowed to ask questions inside someone else's question I'm making a new question.

I have the following layout:

```
namepspace
{
    public partial class
    {

    protected void Page_Load
    { 
    }

    class Employee
    {

        public static bool employeeType
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to access employeeType in Page_Load, how can I access it?

Comment: What is employeeType? A function? Property?

Comment: You can call it by `Employee.employeeType` because it is static. But your employeeType syntax is not right

Comment: why can't you just put Employee.employeeType in the Page_Load event?  what have you tried?  What error did you get?

Comment: I edited the code.  Currently it's a bool. My applogies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
protected void Page_Load
{
    // We can access whitout creating a instance since it is static
    Employee.employeeType
}
```

Doesn't work? Also, what exactly is employeeType? If it is a function:

```
protected void Page_Load
{
     Employee.employeeType();
}
```

But then you are missing the parenthesis and the return type on the declaration. You should declare like this, preferably starting with uppercase (call it with uppercase also):

```
class Employee
{
    public static void EmployeeType()
    {

    }
    ....
}
```

### Edit

So, it is a static property. Then:

```
protected void Page_Load
{
     bool type = Employee.EmployeeType;
}

class Employee
{
    public static bool EmployeeType
    {
        get { return true; }  // Your logic here...
    }
    ....
}
```